# How to use promise to do serial tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

So I have 4 tasks: `getStatus()`, `updateStatus(A)`, `getTask()`, `updateTask()`, it should be executed in this way:

```
getStatus(function(status) {
  // A
  updateStatus(status, function(status) {
    // B
    getTask(function(task) {
      // C
      updateTask(task, function(task) {
        // D
      })
    })
  })
})
```

So in order to avoid callback hell, I used promise, now all these four tasks return a Promise, then I changed it to this way

```
getStatus().then(function(status) {
  // A
  updateStatus(status).then(function(status) {
    // B
    getTask().then(function(task) {
      // C
      updateTask(task).then(function(task) {
        //D
      })
    })
  }) 
})
```

As you can see, it still has `then hell`,

Am I doing something wrong with Promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
getStatus().then(function(status) {
  // A
   return updateStatus(status)
}).then(function(status){
   return updateStatus(status)
}).then(function(status) {
  return getTask()
}).then(function(task) {
      // C
  return updateTask(task)
}).then(function(task) {
     //D
    return getStatus();
}).then(function(newStatus){
     // here you have newStatus returned by getStatus() in D
})
```

And there is no call back hell anymore ;)

Comment: How to get status returned by `getStatus` in `D`?

Comment: @Sato, that's something extra that was not asked in the question. A range of solutions is offered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain/). Your nested approach is probably the best solution. Just remember to add some returns.

Comment: @Sato just return it in `D` and it will be available to the next `.then( function(status){/*status available here*/})`

Answer (score 5):

If you don’t need to use `status` in C and D, this use of `.then` will result in a promise that resolves to `task`:

```
getStatus()
    .then(updateStatus)
    .then(() => getTask())
    .then(updateTask)
```

There’s also [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
const status = await getStatus();
await updateStatus(status);

const task = await getTask();
await updateTask(task);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get status returned by getStatus in D . you can do like this

```
function getStatus ( //here return promise)
function updateStatus( //here return promise)
function updateTask( //here return promise)
```

after this

```
Promise.all([
    getStatus(),updateStatus(),updateTask() 
]).spread(function(a, b,c) {
   //here a = result of getStatus
   //here b = result of updateStatus
   //here c = result of updateTask
});
```

Comment: `Promise.all()` is a promise aggregator, not a function caller.

Comment: It delends upon requirement, We can call functions